# querySelector syntax for class with space

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to refer in jQuery to an element I saved earlier in a page.
I have an element such as

```
<span id="myId" class="super-span super">CONTENT</span>
```

When I save the reference to this content, I get a text variable like:

```
span#myId.super-span super
```

this reference cannot be chosen with jQuery, and returns *undefined*:

```
var myLocation = myElementTag + myElementId + myElementClassName;
console.log($(myPriceLocation).text());
```

How can I modify my code in order to ensure i get back my field value ?

Comment: Regardless of your "technical" question, are you sure you need to use such a strict selector? It's usually better to keep some flexibility using a `data-` attribute, or at least a class (which I believe should be only used for styling purposes, but it's another discussion).

Comment: If you already have an `id=` then you don't need the class parts - assuming of course that you've followed the guidelines and only used that `id` once on the page.

Answer (score 4):

A space is the delimiter in a `class` attribute of a HTML element. As such you need to use a CSS/jQuery selector with no spaces, but separating each class with a `.`, like this:

```
$('span#myId.super-span.super').text();
```